# Float: left not working with WP theme using Foundation 4

Tags: php, wordpress, css-float, zurb-foundation

I'm developing a custom page for my theme (I am using Foundation 4) to show posts of a specific category. I'm trying to put the excerpt in box (using a 4 columns class) which shows the thumbnail of the post too.

The problem is the boxes are getting lined below of the each other (see the link for a printscreen):

http://goo.gl/Kj4uwC

And here's the code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="row">
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(''); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php query_posts('cat=12'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="row" >
<div class="large-12 columns" >
<div class="large-4 columns panel" style="float:left">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');?> </a>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<p class="button radius radius small"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Ler matéria</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
<?php endif; ?>   
</div
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I would love if someone could help to fix this!! thank very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `<div class="row">` it will skip to the next line.  If you want to have three items in the same row (and your items total only 3), then you would set up your output to be like:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- Start loop -->
  <div class="large-4 columns">

  </div>
<!-- End loop which would have created 3 * the large-4 columns divs -->
</div>
```

If you want 3 items per line and could have any number of items kicked out by your loop, then it is best to use the block grid.  It would be set up like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <ul class="large-block-grid-3>
    <!-- Start loop -->
      <li><li>
    <!-- End loop which will create however many li that you need, and place them 3 per row -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but I think that wouldn't work in my case because there's a loop in the php code... but thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you only pull 3 items or can there be many different items?  If only 3, then you place the `<div class="row">` outside of the loop.  If you have any number of items, then maybe consider using the block grid instead.  I have added to my answer above to include this.